# How to cycle through SQL query on multiple datasets?

Tags: arrays, r, loops, simplify

I want to simplify some code that I am running.  I am trying to pull the dimensions of multiple datasets that result from SQL queries.  I want to try to loop through the dataset names

I have been able to get my desired result, I'm just not sure it's the most efficient way of going about this:  I have a separate SQL query line for each dataset.

This is the original code:

```
    library(sqldf)
    dim(sqldf("select Group1, count(*) as Count from Data1 group by Group1"))[1]
    dim(sqldf("select Group1, count(*) as Count from Data2 group by Group1"))[1]
    dim(sqldf("select Group1, count(*) as Count from DataN group by Group1"))[1]
```

This is my attempt at simplifying the code:

```
    datalist=c(Data1,Data2,...DataN)
    abc=vector("list",length(datalist))
    for (i in seq_along(datalist))
      abc[[i]]=dim(sqldf("select Group1, count(*) as Count from datalist[i] group by Group1"))[1]
```

I expect the output to show N numbers for each dataset but I get an error message that reads "no such table: datalist."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the "datalist[i]" within the string does not get substituted by actual value of the `datalist[i]` variable, but passed on to SQL. Try

```
datalist=c("Data1", "Data2", ... "DataN")
queries <- sprintf("select Group1, count(*) as Count from %s group by Group1", datalist)
abc <- lapply(queries, function(q) {
           nrow(sqldf(q))
         })
```

Some additional remarks:

- don't use `for` to populate a list, use `lapply` which directly generates the list
- if you do, there is no need to initialize a list other than `abc <- list()`
- don't use `dim(x)[1]`, `nrow` is more explicit
- if your data is always "Data1", "Data2"... etc, you can also do

  ```
  queries <- sprintf("select Group1, count(*) as Count from Data%d group by Group1", 1:10)
  ```